# Разместить компоненты пропорционально во весь экран

Tags: android, android-layout

Вот пытаюсь написать калькулятор, но вот не могу понять как сделать, что бы кнопки пропорционально заполняли всю область экрана по вертикали. Макет:GridLayout, целевая платформа API 16.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Могу ошибаться (давно не работал с этим лэйаутом). Не пробовали фиксированное количество строк указать? И `GridLaout` по высоте не `wrap_content` случайно?

Comment: ну строки там я так понял не указать, только количество столбцов... а далее они как бы один за другим заполняется друг за другом вправо.. По высоте именно wrap content, но если на match parent, то они растягиваются первые четыре кнопки, а другие уходят вниз за пределы экрана

Comment: Прикрепите лучше xml код

Comment: http://astar3d.ru/chat/layout.zip

Comment: Код необходимо прикреплять в вопросе в специальном блоке и в отформатированном виде. Редактируйте вопрос.

Comment: Как [сверстать калькулятор](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/gridlayout.php). Код, относящийся к вопросу должен содержатся в вопросе в виде текста, а не в каком то архиве, который конечно никто не будет скачивать и смотреть.

Comment: Лейаут в студию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `TableLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:stretchColumns="*">

      <TableRow
         android:layout_height="0dp" <!-- ключ к распределению строк по высоте -->
         android:layout_weight="1" >
         <!-- кнопки -->
         <Button>  

         </Button>
      </TableRow>
      <!-- blah-blah -->
   </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Более гибкой альтернативой GridLayout и TableLayout для конкретного случая может быть использован вертикальный LinearLayout в котором размещены горизонтальные LinearLayout с равным  весом weight. В каждом из них кнопки тоже определены с равным весом

`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <View
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сморится менее локанично, но появляются способы подгонки для которых, чтобы их задать через TableLayout, нужно повозится.